# How to get result from a JavaScript file in Java

Tags: javascript, java

I downloaded a JavaScript file from the [following link](http://74415866fb39db64f965-77255cefef78993e5a5f15d5b0b4abeb.r67.cf1.rackcdn.com/goldprice/js/base.bundle.514cd8b9.js)

I stored this code into 'goldprice.js'
Then I somehow minimized the whole HTML code from  [here](http://goldprice.org/) 
 to the following simplified code.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>
Gold Price: 
<xyz id="gpotickerLeft_price"></xyz>
</h1>
<script src="goldprice.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var leftticker
var ticker = new GPOTicker();
    ticker.addTicker(leftticker, 'gpotickerLeft');
    ticker.start();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my question is how to get this whole thing working in Java program? I want the output of the above HTML code in my Java program so that I may be able to use that automatically updated value in jlabel.

I have seen some examples on

**javax.script.ScriptEngine** and 
**javax.script.ScriptEngineManager** 
but I don't really think my problem is that simple.

Comment: the linked javascript file is just the jquery library. I dont think this is what you want. Its a library used by web developers but has nothing to do with gold prices.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the above html doesn't work without <script src="goldprice.js"></script>. I don't have any experience in using web side stuff, and i don't really understand javascript or jquery at all. All i want is to grab gold price form the above mentioned website in my java program.

Comment: You'r e right. I was mislead by the comment at the script's top. It seems they added the GPOTicker() code into the jquery script, or it has all been compressed to one javascript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closer loook to the javascript code, you'll find, that the javascript fetches the actual data from a webservice. Look for the code that starts with

```
{api2:"http://api2.goldprice.org/Service.svc/GetRaw/",resourcesRootPath:"/goldprice/img/"
```

That seems to be their webservice, which you could try to access directly from Java. Note, however, that you ought to ask for the permission to use that service. If it is an service that is meant to be officially used by others, there should exist a documentation and all to explain how to use it. That would be the best way to go.

Comment: It seems like what i am looking for is not that simple. I searched on the web for how to get data values from web services and figured it out that it was beyond the scope of JavaSE. Moreover it may not be the legitimate way to do it. Thank you for your reply.